# Passing a Private String in Java

Tags: java, private

I need to get the string randomWord to return through getWord()

```
    private static void setUpDictionary() throws IOException
{

    Scanner fileScan;
    String[] words = new String[25];

    fileScan = new Scanner (new File("dictionary.dat")); 
    int n=0;
    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        words[n] = fileScan.next();
        n++; 
    }

    int rand = (int) (Math.random()*n);

    String randomWord = words[rand];
    System.out.println("TEST THIS IS RANDOM WORD ..." + randomWord);

    fileScan.close();
}

//Returns random word from dictionary array
private static String getWord()
{
    String word = randomWord ;
    return word;    
}
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

The only error comes from 
       `String word = randomWord ;`
because randomWord isn't a string in getWord().

So how do I make randomWord available to getWord()?

EDITS:
I cannot change any existing private, they have to stay private.

Comment: you can't do this with static methods.

Comment: how/where r u calling getword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `randomWord` as a new String object in your `setUpDictionary()` method. It should be a member attribute of the class instead, so that it can be referenced in other methods within the class' scope.

Example:

```
private static String randomWord;

private static void setUpDictionary() throws IOException {
    // ...
    randomWord = words[rand];
    // ...
}

private static String getWord() {
    return randomWord;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. As others have posted in this thread, you should reconsider whether or not you need to make these methods static. Are you instantiating the class these are part of, and thus have a reference to use? If so, get rid of the static methods. If, instead, you're calling them with the class name (as you do with Math.random()), then leave them in.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that these methods belong to a class. Firstly remove the `static` modifiers. Second, make `String word;` a private member of this class.

```
public class MyDictionary {
    String word;

    private void setUpDictionary() {
        ////////
        word = words[rand];
        ////////
    }

    private String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
}
```

Comment: cant change the privates, they have to stay private.

Comment: @Brett that's no problem. make them private.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String randomWord="";
  private static void setUpDictionary() throws IOException
{

    Scanner fileScan;
    String[] words = new String[25];

    fileScan = new Scanner (new File("dictionary.dat")); 
    int n=0;
    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        words[n] = fileScan.next();
        n++; 
    }

    int rand = (int) (Math.random()*n);

    randomWord = words[rand];
    System.out.println("TEST THIS IS RANDOM WORD ..." + randomWord);

    fileScan.close();
}

//Returns random word from dictionary array
public static String getWord()
{
try{
setUpDictionary();
}catch(Exception exp){}

return randomWord;
}
```